# Android library .aar with dagger + application part depends on aar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, aar

I have a question about dagger 2 and the possibilities to extends some components or modules.

In my case: I have a library (.aar file), it's part of the application. 
Inside that file is defined AARComponent that has some modules e.g. AARActivityBuilder.
And that AARComponent is initialized in Application class.

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, AARActivityBuilder::class, AARModule::class)
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(app: AARApplication)
}

class AARApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        DaggerAARComponent
                    .builder()
                    .applicationModule(new AARModule(this))
                    .build()
                    .inject(this)
    }
}
```

But the second part depends on that library and I'd like to add some modules (usually activities) that are defined only here. 
But I want to use dependencies from the library as well.

Example:
AAR file has an abstract class A.

Application that imports aar library has class B that inhertis from class A.
So I need method with annotation @ContributesAndroidInjector which returns class B but .aar file does not know about class B.

I was trying to extend AARComponent but in vain. Also I was trying to create new @Component interface and add AARComponent as dependencies. But also did not work. Maybe I missed something or did wrong.

Is there any good method to do this?

Thanks